# error with delete button with list box

Tags: vb.net

At the moment the code that I have used *enables* me to delete a `selected item` from the *list box*, however when clicking on the delete button without anything selected from the list the program freezes and i get the `error: InvalidArgument=Value of '-1' is not valid for 'index'`.

Can I make it such that nothing happens to the program upon clicking the delete button while nothing from the list is selected?

```
Private Sub Delbtn_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Delbtn.Click

    lstCountries.Items.RemoveAt(lstCountries.SelectedIndex)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just check if the selected index is not -1 and only then call `RemoveAt`.

```
if (lstCountries.SelectedIndex != -1)
    lstCountries.Items.RemoveAt(lstCountries.SelectedIndex);
```

Or in VB.net:

```
If lstCountries.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
    lstCountries.Items.RemoveAt(lstCountries.SelectedIndex)
End If
```

But a better solution is to enable/disable the delete button dependent of if there is an item selected (e.g. with the event handler `SelectedIndexChanged`).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm new to the coding language so as a follow up, why use <> instead of = ?

Comment: <> means "not equal". So you check for a value that is NOT -1 and only then call `RemoveAt`. You can also check if the selected index is greater than -1 or greater-or-equal than 0.